# why order by not working together group by?

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am having news table and there are 4 categories in the news and I want get every category's latest news(sort by date). I have used following query :

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
   term_data.tid AS term_data_tid,
   node.type AS node_type,
   node.vid AS node_vid,
   node.title AS node_title,
   node_data_field_blog_overview.field_blog_overview_value AS node_data_field_blog_overview_field_blog_overview_value,
   node_data_field_blog_overview.field_blog_overview_format AS node_data_field_blog_overview_field_blog_overview_format,
   term_data.name AS term_data_name,
   term_data.vid AS term_data_vid,
   users.name AS users_name,
   users.uid AS users_uid,
   node.created AS node_created,
   node_data_field_blog_overview.field_feed_author_name_value AS node_data_field_blog_overview_field_feed_author_name_value,
   node.sticky AS node_sticky
 FROM node node 
 LEFT JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid
 LEFT JOIN term_data term_data ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid
 LEFT JOIN content_field_image node_data_field_image ON node.vid = node_data_field_image.vid
 LEFT JOIN content_type_blog node_data_field_blog_overview ON node.vid = node_data_field_blog_overview.vid
 INNER JOIN users users ON node.uid = users.uid
 WHERE (node.type in ('blog')) AND (node.status <> 0)
 GROUP BY term_data_name order by node_created
  LIMIT 5
```

why i am not getting each category's latest news using above query?

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: I am getting old dated news

Comment: I am getting same output with desc and asc

Comment: My suggestion would be to read the [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) about group by. You are not using an aggregate functions with the GROUP BY and you are not grouping by all of the columns in your select list, this means that _the server is free to choose any value from each group_. The ORDER BY will not guarantee the correct result.

Comment: i have applied max on node created but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem starts with the the JOIN types and their order.  I would suggest anytime you are grouping data, to use the group by fields' table as the `FROM` table.

To simplify, start with just getting the latest time of each category's most recent article:

```
SELECT term_data.name, MAX(node.node_created) AS mostrecent
FROM term_data
JOIN term_node
  ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid
JOIN node node 
 ON node.vid = term_node.vid
WHERE (node.type in ('blog')) AND (node.status <> 0)
GROUP BY term_data.name
```

Then you can use that to get more of the articles

```
SELECT {your field list}
FROM [insert above query] AS latest_news
JOIN term_data
  ON term_data.name = latest_news.name
JOIN term_node
  ON term_node.tid = term_data.tid
JOIN node node 
  ON node.vid = term_node.vid
    AND latest_news.mostrecent = node.node_created
JOIN users users
  ON node.uid = users.uid
LEFT JOIN content_field_image node_data_field_image 
  ON node.vid = node_data_field_image.vid
LEFT JOIN content_type_blog node_data_field_blog_overview 
  ON node.vid = node_data_field_blog_overview.vid
```